# Winter bash dropdown title hover color is wrong

Tags: feature-request, design, winter-bash-2014

Clicking the snowflake and hovering over winter bash (all caps for some reason) makes it turn brown! Winter isn't brown! "I hate hats" can be brown because those who click it hate fun and deserve brown.

Can it be made another color? Or underline on hover instead?

Comment: I have to agree, it makes the well known advice even worse - "Don't eat *brown* snow"..

Answer (score 6):

Upon inspection, the color fades to a "Dark orange [Brown tone]" according to http://www.colorhexa.com/955e13.

[image]
<sub>(source: [colorhexa.com](http://www.colorhexa.com/955e13.png))</sub>

In a word, eww.

Clearly what winter deserves is a nice strong pine color. http://www.colorhexa.com/03573d

[image]
<sub>(source: [colorhexa.com](http://www.colorhexa.com/03573d.png))</sub>

[image]